# Integral extension of a local ring is also local?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I suppose this is a classical result, but I'm having problems to prove it.

> I want to prove that if $R$ is a commutative local ring and $R\subset S$ is an integral extension, then $S$ is also local.

To start with, I know that $\dim(R) = \dim(S)$ and that the Going Up property holds. I tried to get a contradiction if we suppose $S$ has two distinct maximal ideals. Denote by $\mathfrak{m}_1, \mathfrak{m}_2$ this ideals, of course their height is less or equal $\dim(R)$, which is the height of the only maximal ideal of $R$. Now I considered the primes $R\cap\mathfrak{m}_1,R\cap\mathfrak{m}_2$. Both are maximal right? So this is the contradiction.

I'm a little concerned about this reasoning because I didn't use the two properties stated at the beginning: the dimension and the Going Up property. In fact, $R\cap\mathfrak{m}_1,R\cap\mathfrak{m}_2$ will be maximal even if the extension is not integral. I think my reasoning don't need the extension to be integral and this is suspicious.

I need some light in this proof, thanks.

Comment: Why is the statement "Both are maximal" a contradiction?

Comment: @Andrew Because, by the definition, $R$ has only one maximal ideal.

Comment: What if $R\bigcap \mathfrak{m}_1=R\bigcap \mathfrak{m}_2$?

Comment: I thought about this, but I don`t know how to work this idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can't prove that result because it's false!

Counterexample: $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2-1)$.

Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $S$. Then $R/(M\cap R)\subset S/M$ is an integral extension of integral domains, and $S/M$ is a field, so $R/(M\cap R)$ is also a field. This shows that $M\cap R$ equals the maximal ideal of $R$, and this is *all* one can get.